# Permissions of files within subfolders with SGID in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a file server based on Ubuntu 14.04. Many users do exist in it where each user belongs to its own group (such as lucas:lucas) but also to a common group called "sambashared".

```
lucas@arturito:~$ cat /etc/group | grep lucas
adm:x:4:lucas,syslog
lp:x:7:saned,lucas
cdrom:x:24:lucas
sudo:x:27:lucas
dip:x:30:lucas
plugdev:x:46:lucas
lucas:x:1000:
lpadmin:x:111:lucas
sambashare:x:112:lucas
```

There is also a shared folder under the /home: /home/share. Such a folder has the SGID bit enabled, so files created under it will belong to the "sambashare" group:

```
lucas@arturito:/home$ ls -l | grep samba
drwxrwsr-x 10 share      sambashare  4096 Apr 24 13:44 share
lucas@arturito:/home/share$ touch test.text
lucas@arturito:/home/share$ ls -l test.text
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lucas sambashare 0 Apr 24 14:02 test.text
```

So, as seen before, the files being created under /home/share are created fine (lucas:sambashare). The issue I'm having is for files being created on a deeper subfolder of /home/share:

```
lucas@arturito:/home/share/99_varios$ touch file.txt
lucas@arturito:/home/share/99_varios$ ls -l | grep file.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas         0 Apr 24 14:19 file.txt
```

If you see before, the file file.txt belongs to lucas:lucas, but I was hoping it to be lucas:sambashare.

Any idea on how to solve this? Or, is it solvable?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

Comment: Hi! I'm receiving downvotes for this question but I'm not sure why... Is the question not clear at all? Is it too simple or basic? ... instead of getting downvotes blindly, it would at least be of help some clarification of why someone is voting it negative ...

Comment: Can you not just manually change to permissions ?

Comment: Hi @JID, I can certainly modify the permissions manually. Thing is the following: it's a multi user server and I was hoping that the permissions would be assigned properly on every file creation (ssh is the most common access method). I have complaints of users coming back to me from time to time saying they cannot modify any given file because of permission issues. I thought SGID would solve it but is not sufficient ...

Comment: Don't know if this will be useful http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1196997

Comment: Thanks @JID, I'll have a look at it to see if I get any hint ....

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is to use facl (file access control lists).

```
setfacl -m default:group:sambashare:rw /home/samba
```

All new files in */home/samba* and its sub-folders will be owned by *lucas:lucas* but *sambashare* group will have read and write permission.

More in [getfact (1)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/getfacl1.html) and [setfact (1)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html).